# gcc float pointer casting in C++ causing SIGBUS error

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, casting, segmentation-fault

I have an dynamically defined array of unsigned 8 bit integers:

```
const uint8_t *data;
```

This contains a bytestream, and is reinterpreted as various data types. I can reinterpret a position *n* in this data stream as a fundamental type *type* by:

```
type value =  *((type*) &data[n]);
```

This works fine for all data types using the Visual Studio Compiler under Windows, however when compiling under Linux using gcc, this creates a SIGBUS error when *type* is a float (the dereferenced location is within the range of the data array). Further investigation shows that it is the pointer dereferencing that is causing this error. I have solved this by using memcpy, but would like to know why this causes a problem in the first place seeing as the address that is referenced is valid. Would a reinterpret_cast be more suitable, and if so, why?

EDIT:

I did not mention that the Linux system has an ARM architecture. @MSalters has pointed out below that there may be more stringent pointer alignment requirements for difference configurations. A short research shows that while the above is valid on x86 architectures (although not allowed by C / C++ standards), unaligned pointer dereferencing on ARM will cause a bus error.

Comment: If you are doing this jiggery-pokery i would consider another look at the design

Comment: Does it happen only with floats? Or for other types the same size as float?

Comment: The design is for a network protocol that allows communication over rs232 interfaces, and something that will sit on top of tcp/ip. The data types are defined in frame headers, and so this sort of interpretation is needed.

Comment: @Hampycalc - I doubt it. You just need to serialise and deserialise the data.

Comment: "*This works fine for all data types* ..." Well, it happens to do what you happen to want. I wouldn't really describe that as "works fine".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cast is indeed the problem. It's already a `reinterpret_cast`, even though you used the old C syntax. But the cast is only allowed when `&data[n]` actually is a valid `float*`. `SIGBUS` means it isn't. The address may be a valid `char*` address, but that doesn't mean it's a valid `float*` address. In particular, `float*` may have more stringent alignment requirements.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I did not mention that the Linux system is ARM based, and the Windows one is x86 / x86_64. I have not had problems with alignment requirements before, but my experience has been solely on x86 CPU architectures. I will be sticking to using memcpy in the future to keep my code fully portable.

Comment: Well, x86 isn't happy with alignment errors either, but the penalty is jus a slowdown.

Comment: That was worth mentioning! ARM is very picky about alignment, you get away with murder on x86.

Comment: Yes, very useful stuff. I'm guessing an std::memcpy() would be the best solution?

Comment: That's pretty safe, yes.

Answer (score 5):

As MSalters mentions in this thread, the alignment requirement of the destination type of the cast is stronger than that of your source type, which causes `SIGBUS` on CPUs that do not handle unaligned access.

The way to deal with that is `memcpy`:

```
const uint8_t *data = ...;
type value;
memcpy(&value, data, sizeof value);
```